# Printing colorful non-ASCII characters to CLI

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, colors, non-ascii-characters

I have utilised the Colorful Console nuget:

```
<PackageReference Include="Colorful.Console" Version="1.2.15" />
```

With the intention of printing non-ASCII characters to a console app in Powershell:

```
using Console = Colorful.Console;
...
Console.Write("•", Color.Gray);
```

But this does not display anything in powershell or the VSCode Terminal.

Am I missing something or is powershell simply not able to display that character when colorised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For full Unicode support on Windows, **make sure your console's code page is `65001` (UTF-8)** before calling your program:

- from `cmd.exe`:

  - `chcp 65001`
- from PowerShell:

  - `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`

Unless you happen to have used the still-in-beta Windows 10 feature that activates *system*-wide UTF-8 support (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375)), your default OEM (console) code page is a fixed, single-byte encoding such as [`437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems, which is limited to 256 characters and therefore cannot represent Unicode characters such as `•` (BULLET, [`U+2022`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022)).

Seemingly, with code page `437` in effect, `•` degrades to an *invisible* ASCII-range control character (ALERT, [`U+0007`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7)).

Note:

- This behavior is not specific to the `Colorful.Console` package; it equally applies to the built-in `Console.WriteLine()`.
- Changing a console's code page can affect other programs, so you may have to restore the original one.